# Issue with indexof and substring

Tags: c#

Now after I solved by help here getting the text from between two tags in a small text file that I created for testing with only 4 lines. Now I want to create a new text file that will contain the content of the original file but in every place where I found the text between the tags I want to see spaces empty string. So if the original text file is looks like this now:

```
daniel<Text>THISISOUTisthere</Text>
<Text>hellobye</Text>
<Text>danielTHISishereandnotthere</Text>
danie <Text> is THIS here and not THERE</Text>
```

So the new file should looks like:

```
daniel<Text>                </Text>
<Text>        </Text>
<Text>                            </Text>
danie <Text>                           </Text>
```

Here is the code that doesn't work now. I used some help variables but I'm getting an error when running this code on the line:

```
string hh = f.Substring(lastIndex, currentIndex);
```

The error say: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length

This is the complete code now which doesn't work:

```
private void test()
        {
            w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\testFile.txt");
            int currentLength;
            int currentIndex;
            int lastIndex = 0;
            string startTag = "<Text>";
            string endTag = "</Text>";
            int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
            //int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
            index = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                index = f.IndexOf(startTag, index);
                if (index == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                // else more to do - index now is positioned at first character of startTag    
                int start = index + startTagWidth;
                currentIndex = start;
                index = f.IndexOf(endTag, start+1);
                if (index == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                // found the endTag    
                string g = f.Substring(start, index - start - 1);
                currentLength = index - start - 1;
                string hh = f.Substring(lastIndex, currentIndex);
                w.WriteLine(hh);
                lastIndex = currentIndex + currentLength;
                listBox1.Items.Add(g);
            } 
        }
```

Please help me with this code.

Comment: **Use an XML parser**.

Comment: Or an HTML parser, if you want to allow quirks HTML...

Comment: @SLaks That won't work, the file does not appear to be valid XML

Comment: I know you asked for help with your code but why are you solving it this way?  From what I can tell this might actually be a decent case for using a regular expression (with the caveat that I don't know what the full set of expected test cases are).

Comment: @Daniel - Is there the potential for there to be something like <Text> foo<bar></Text> in the file?

Comment: it's possible that this is an exercise to understand more about how parsers work; and he's not allowed to use built in parsers

Comment: @Bob: Just wrap it in an outer tag and it will be valid.

Answer (score 1):

substring takes a length as its second parameter not a index position so it should be

```
string hh = f.Substring(lastIndex, currentIndex-lastIndex);
```

additionally you are chopping too many characters off, you want to change `currentLength = index - start -1` to be `currentLength = index - start`

And finally using `Writeline` will be puttin addtional line feeds in, use `Write` instead.

Answer (score 1):

For a fun alternative, you could use a regular expression to do the replacement for you:

```
string input = "daniel<Text>THISISOUTisthere</Text>\n<Text>hellobye</Text>\n<Text>danielTHISishereandnotthere</Text>\ndanie <Text> is THIS here and not THERE</Text>";
Regex re = new Regex("(?<=<Text>).*?(?=</Text>)");
string output = re.Replace(input, m => new string(' ', m.Length));

Console.WriteLine(input);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Program output:

```
daniel<Text>THISISOUTisthere</Text>
<Text>hellobye</Text>
<Text>danielTHISishereandnotthere</Text>
danie <Text> is THIS here and not THERE</Text>

daniel<Text>                </Text>
<Text>        </Text>
<Text>                           </Text>
danie <Text>                           </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another fun alternative, as I felt like I wanted to try to get it to work: A small do-it-yourself parser.

***Note:** This is by far not a real HTML or XML parser! It only involes one single tag (e.g. `<Text>`) and only without any attributes...*

So, what do you need for a parser? Right, a tokenizer. Here you go:

```
static IEnumerable<Token> Tokenize(string input, string tag)
{
    int index = 0;
    int lastIndex = 0;

    // Define the start and end tag and their common first character
    char tagChar = '<';
    string startTag = tag + '>';
    string endTag = '/' + tag + '>';

    while (true)
    {
        Token token = null;

        // Search for any new tag token
        index = input.IndexOf(tagChar, index) + 1;
        if (index <= 0)
            break;

        // Starttag or endtag token found
        if (input.Substring(index, startTag.Length) == startTag)
            token = new Token { Start = index - 1, Length = startTag.Length + 1, TypeOfToken = Token.TokenType.StartTag };
        else if (input.Substring(index, endTag.Length) == endTag)
            token = new Token { Start = index - 1, Length = endTag.Length + 1, TypeOfToken = Token.TokenType.EndTag };

        // Yield the text right before the tag and the tag itself
        if (token != null)
        {
            yield return new Token { Start = lastIndex, Length = index - lastIndex - 1, TypeOfToken = Token.TokenType.Text };
            yield return token;
            lastIndex = index + token.Length - 1;
        }
    }

    // Yield last text token
    yield return new Token { Start = lastIndex, Length = input.Length - lastIndex, TypeOfToken = Token.TokenType.Text };
}

class Token
{
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public TokenType TypeOfToken { get; set; }

    public enum TokenType
    {
        Text,
        StartTag,
        EndTag
    }
}
```

It is even somewhat optimized, as it only searches for `<` and checks if it is a start or end tag afterwards.

Having the string tokenized, the rest of the processing is quite simple:

```
static string ProcessString(string input, string tag)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    int depth = 0;
    foreach (var token in Tokenize(input, tag))
    {
        // Append all tags, but only text tokens with depth level 0
        if (token.TypeOfToken != Token.TokenType.Text || 
            (token.TypeOfToken == Token.TokenType.Text && depth == 0))
            sb.Append(input.Substring(token.Start, token.Length));
        else
            sb.Append(new string(' ', token.Length));

        // Increment for each starttag, decrement for each endtag, never smaller than 0
        depth = Math.Max(0, depth + (token.TypeOfToken == Token.TokenType.StartTag ? 1 :
                                    (token.TypeOfToken == Token.TokenType.EndTag ? -1 : 0)));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This is quite a bit more flexible than the regex solution, because you can give it more semantic meaning, like the depth. For example calling this:

```
ProcessString("level0<Tag>level1<Tag>level2</Tag>level1again</Tag>level0again", "Tag");
```

will be processed to this:

```
"level0<Tag>      <Tag>      </Tag>           </Tag>level0again"
```